# Python RegEx Underlying Character Groups - eg: Can [0-A] be used?

Tags: python, regex

This is valid `r'[A-Za-z0-9]'`, so is this `r'[0-A]'` - I would like to know what characters class is being matched here.

What is the underlying character table for Python's (2.7) `re` module?
Do `[A-Z]`, `[a-z]`, `[0-9]` reference separate tables or is a single, *whole*, indexed table such as [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com)? What defines the character table(s) to be used?

I am asking to understand the underlying mechanism.

Comment: Are you just asking about how to use character class ranges? You can define your own ones, `[1-A]` is valid, the point is that the min part should have a lower index compared to the max one. *The hyphen defines a range between two characters in the ASCII table (or between two Unicode code points, depending on the engine). But a range does not have to look like `[a-z]`*

Comment: That's what I wanted to know - whether or not one whole (eg ASCII) table is being used, or multiple separate tables. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character range will be based on ASCII or Unicode, depending on the version of Python and the type of the string. If you look up the character values, you'll see that there's a whole bunch of characters in between `'9'` and `'A'` that will be included that you probably didn't intend.

```
>>> r = re.compile('[0-A]')
>>> r.match('0')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x025E8640>
>>> print r.match('0')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x025E85D0>
>>> print r.match('9')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x025E85D0>
>>> print r.match('A')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x025E85D0>
>>> print r.match('Z')
None
>>> print r.match('-')
None
>>> print r.match(':')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x025E85D0>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just test?

```
>>> import re
>>> p = r'[0-A]'
>>> s = ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(256))
>>> ''.join(re.findall(p, s))
'0123456789:;<=>?@A'
>>> p = r'[0-Z]'
>>> ''.join(re.findall(p, s))
'0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

Comment: Testing will confirm the ranges work, but not tell what the underlying table of characters is.

Answer (score 0):

By default in Python 2 the model is ASCII, but assuming that can be dangerous (it is set in a startup file).   A-Z etc. are not different sets, they are just commonly used sets, although the correct term in *character class*.

Better to use more than one range `[0-9a-x]`, for example.

`[0-A]` is valid but would include a bunch of punctuation characters as well, and probably confuse the heck out of people reading your code.

Don't confuse this with classes such as `\w`, that can change depending on flag settings.